# magit-run-git-with-editor: Invalid function: with-editor*

Tags: magit

today, using `magit`, I've started getting the following error message when I hit `c` to commit :

> Terminal is dumb, but EDITOR unset

In the `*Messages*` buffer, I also get:

> magit-run-git-with-editor: Invalid function: with-editor*

Of course, I have the `with-editor` package installed and up-to-date...
Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update `with-editor` and `magit` (likely in that order). Then restart Emacs. If it still doesn't work then, then uninstall both packages and reinstall `magit` (which also installs `with-editor`). There was a bug, that potentially leaks into byte-code generated while the broken version is already loaded.

Comment: Can here twice... I didn't read the full text the first time.  For me, installing via el-get, I had to do the remove and then reinstall.